# Maximum occurrence of any value in array

Tags: arrays

Consider that I have an array with the following values: { 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4 }. Now, there are three instances of the number 2 and two instances of the value 5 in this array. The maximum number of appearances of any number in this array is three.

I want an output that says 3. How can I do that?

I am a newcomer, and I thought for loop would do this work, but the values of the array can be up to 10^9 and the size of the array can be up to 10^5.I hope someone will find me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently find the maximum number of appearances of any number in the array by using a HashMap:

```
def max_appearances(arr):
    frequency = {}
    max_count = 0

    for num in arr:
        frequency[num] = frequency.get(num, 0) + 1
        max_count = max(max_count, frequency[num])

    return max_count

# Example usage
arr = [7, 1, 1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7]
result = max_appearances(arr)
print(result)  # Output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a special box called a HashMap where we will keep track of how many times we see each number in the array.

Step 2: Imagine we are reading the numbers one by one from the list. For each number, we will do some actions.

Step 3: Check if we have already seen this number before. If we have seen it, we will take a pen and add 1 to the count of that number in our HashMap. If it's the first time we see the number, we will create a new count of 1 for it in our HashMap.

Step 4: While we keep reading numbers and updating our HashMap, we will keep a note of the biggest count we have seen so far.

Step 5: After we finish reading all the numbers and updating our HashMap, we will look at all the counts we have written down. The biggest count we found during our reading is the answer!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4 };
    int maxCount = getMaxAppearanceCount(arr);
    System.out.println(maxCount);
}

public static int getMaxAppearanceCount(int[] arr) {
   
    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>(); // Create a HashMap to store the count of each element

    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int num : arr) {
        
        if (countMap.containsKey(num)) {
            int count = countMap.get(num);
            countMap.put(num, count + 1); // If the element exists in the countMap, increment its count
        } else {
            
            countMap.put(num, 1);// If the element does not exist in the countMap, add it with count 1
        }

       
        maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, countMap.get(num));
    }

    return maxCount;
}
}
```